# Unable to design a HTML/CSS block, can't get images to align using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to design the following block, given in image
[image]

The background image of building is separate from the human image, how can I use bootstrap grid system to align the images and text in this way, also keep the aspect ratio of images?

The background image is spread to 100% but the the content and human image is centered and aligned with other content

Comment: please add some codes

Comment: I think you can add the building background using css and the human image insert it using html and you will achieve the same layout. Try also using positions to style the human image

Comment: Buildings image as background, then a div with background image with the human image as a transparent png, and inside another div with the text stuff. But without the code you've been working it's imposible to see your problem.

Comment: just curious, why dont you photoshop the two images side by side and then use "background-image" property?

Answer (score 2):

Use the building image as background for your `body` tag and the human image as an background for either `.container` or `.row` class.

Also the human image should be aligned right.

Something like

```css
body {
  /* image just for reference*/
  background: url('http://www.eliteconcreterestoration.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/concrete-office-park-buildings.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  /* image just for reference*/
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS2-Dj0_UAhag-zIDaVGoV2LuCIy62nGvt_zNJoeILF1VqM3EXOdK20qR6N');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
.jumbotron {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white !important;
}

.jumbotron .text{
   color:white;
   font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>A good <span style="color:lightgreen;">investment</span> pays the best <span style="color:orange;">interest</span></h1>
        <p class="text">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background:lightgreen;" href="#" role="button">Register</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background:orange;" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this design, you don't (strait forward that is) The hand part will mess up your grid layout. Or merge images, or use a smaller version of your human image that will stay inside the grid (all blocks are squares with Bootstrap, and there is NO layering beyond background image of parent element.).

*** Edit** As [Kishore Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823369/kishore-kumar) Points out, you can. Something like this:

```
<body> <!-- has CSS background with buildings -->
    <div class="container"> <!-- has CSS background with human, float: right -->   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">And more stuff for layout...</div>
        </div
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: so how do i design it?

Comment: `background-image: 'image.jpg' background-position: 'stuff'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do.

1. create a section and give it the background image with `background-size: cover;` property and then use a container inside the section and put my grid.

```html
<section class="building-bg">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- text content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <!-- png image with some negative margins or translate property -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```